# Java multithreading. Same System.currentTimeMillis() values on different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, time

I want to use the result of `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the multithreaded appplication to generate unique IDs. This is my code:

```
    class MyRunnableClass implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long thisValueShouldBeUnique = System.currentTimeMillis ();
        }
    }
```

I start 10 threads which run MyRunnableClass object run() method.
Is it true, that sometimes the result of `System.currentTimeMillis ()` in different threads may be the same?

Comment: unique id's of what? Threads?

Comment: highly possible, you may concate some thread identifier to your unique value

Comment: If you're the one starting the threads, why not give them a unique ID upon initialization? You can also use Thread.currentThread().getId()

Comment: If you want uniqueness, use a GUID instead of a time stamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the current time in milliseconds. So if your threads run during the same millisecond, yes this function will return the same result. So you can generate UUIDs like that: `UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: or more simply an `atomicLong.getAndIncrement();`

Comment: Yes you can, if you want just a simple incrementable ID

Answer (score 3):

Today's CPUs can process around 100,000,000,000 instructions per second, so the answer is definitely "Yes, It is true that sometimes the result of `System.currentTimeMillis()` in different threads may be the same".